# Consulta me arroja datos repetidos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

**Buenas:**
Cuando realizo esta consulta me arroja los datos repetidos que tengo en la tabla (y2018pagos), ¿Hay alguna manera de que me aparezcan una sola vez los datos?

```
$qry = "select alu.id_alumno, matr.curso, matr.fecha,  matr.grado , alu.proceinsti, alu.apellidos, alu.nombres, alu.docutip, alu.genero, alu.docunum, alu.docuexp, alu.genero, alu.lugnace, alu.depnace, alu.paisnace, 
alu.fchnace, alu.correo, alu.celular, fam.apellidos AS  'apellidos_fam', fam.nombres AS  'nombres_fam', 
fam.tipo, fam.direccion, fam.telefono, fam.barrio, fam.docunum AS 'numero_fam'
FROM alumnos alu
INNER JOIN matriculas matr ON matr.id_alumno = alu.id_alumno
INNER JOIN familiares fam ON fam.id_familiar = alu.id_familiar
INNER JOIN y2018pagos pag ON pag.id_alumno = alu.id_alumno
WHERE matr.ano = '".$año."' AND matr.estado = 'CERRADA' AND pag.valor != '0'";

$res = mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: Has probado a usar `SELECT DISTINCT` en lugar de `SELECT` solamente?

Comment: Tienes que revisar el diseño de tu base de datos y cómo tienes establecidas las relaciones. Puede que el problema esté ahí: **en relaciones mal hechas**, hasta puede que en realidad haya datos repetidos y no lo sepas. Sin haber verificado eso, es imposible ayudarte. Si verificas que no tienes datos repetidos, y que las relaciones están bien, entonces explica cómo están diseñadas tus tablas y se podría ver lo que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Bendiciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justo después del "SELECT" usa **DISTINCT** y encierra todo lo que quieras q sea distinto entre paréntesis:

> SELECT DISTINCT (COLUMNA1) FROM ...

Esto se q funciona con **PL/SQL**. No estoy seguro si en otras también

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya me funciono. Bendiciones